# I am not able to reinstall os because i forgot my hardisk unlock password

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, password

My Mac is not working and I tried to reinstall ( pressed command and R key while starting). Reached to utilities but when try to reinstall or restore it asks password after selecting hard disk but I forget the password.

In disk utility, I can see Macintosh HD and disk 1 ( Mac OS x base system) but nothing is erasable and even in Macintosh HD heading is coming but below that hard disk is not selectable)